API is working fine in dev mode(localhost://3000) but not in production
I am currently working on a Next.js project that uses Hono as the backend framework and Neon as the database. During development, all APIs function correctly on localhost (http://localhost:3000). However, after deploying the project to Vercel, the APIs fail to work as expected, despite having added the necessary environment variables to Vercel. I have changed a varaible from NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL= http://localhost:3000/ to NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL= https://expense-mate-amber.vercel.app/ as in production vercel assigned me this domain, but still getting 500 Internal Server Error.

I can confirm that the link works and the login form is accessible: Login Form. The API is functioning correctly as well.
Can you provide the steps to reproduce the 500 error?

For login I used the clerk. If you sign up and login, you'll see the dashboard page. Please navigate to account page and check if account are displayed. If api works, please add some dummy accounts for you to confirm
